# R language: changes to the value of an attribute of an object inside a function is lost after function exits

Tags: r, attributes

I have simple R code as follows:

```
change <- function(x, v) {
  attr(x, 'abc') <- v
  attributes(x)
}

change(iris$Sepal.Length, 't1')
attributes(iris$Sepal.Length)
```

the result shows:

```
> change(iris$Sepal.Length, 't1')
$abc
[1] "t1"

> attributes(iris$Sepal.Length)
NULL
```

as you can see, attributes(x) printed inside the function shows x (which is iris$Sepal.Length) has the attribute abc as t1. but after function is called, attributes(iris$Sepal.Length) shows 'abc' is not defined anymore.

Anyone knows why? How can I change object's attribute inside a function using passed arguments?

Comment: Heck, even changes to the value of an object would be lost with that sort of code. R IS A FUNCTIONAL LANGUAGE. Why am I shouting? Because you are using logic from experiences with a procedural language. Instead, you need to understand that changes to an object inside a function body do not affect the value of that object outside UNLESS you assign the changes to the original name. Your code should be renamed `change_inside_but_not_yet_real`. Furthermore to change the attributes, use `attributes(iris$Sepal.Length) <- change(iris$Sepal.Length, 't1')`

Comment: I was trying to change attribute by parameters, as I have a bunch of attributes of an object to change, instead of writing them line by line, I was trying to put the attribute name in a list, then lapply() to change them in one line.  Any way to do that?

Comment: There is an attr<- function which you are possibly using  correctly so it should be fairly simple. You are not showing in your question that you have understood my comments. You should edit your question body to show that you know how to make the “change” stick. This will require a full [MCVE]